In Python with Polars: when extending expressions why are my column names being passed to my python function, instead of values?
I am trying to use expression extensions to apply my previously built and tested function that performs a vlookup on a dict named 'GBP to return a rateon a given date.
The problem is that the custom extension is passing the column names rather than their values to my original function.
I am new to polars, but not to python, and am having difficulty understanding the cause of the problem.
Here is my code:
def get_single_rate(cur,amount,target_date,reverse = True):
  print("cur variable (should == 'GBP') = '{}'\namount variable (should be in [35,55]) = '{}'\ntarget_date variable (should be in ['2024-04-23','2024-04-26']) = '{}'\n ".format(cur,amount,target_date))

@pl.api.register_lazyframe_namespace("myconversions")
class ConversionOperations:
    def __init__(self, ldf: pl.LazyFrame):
        self._ldf = ldf

    def convert(self) -> pl.LazyFrame:
        return self._ldf.with_columns(
            get_single_rate("currency","amount","date")[0])

df = pl.scan_csv('test.csv').collect()
print(df)
df = pl.scan_csv('test.csv').myconversions.convert().collect()
print(df)

The expected output:
cur variable (should == 'GBP') = 'GBP'  
amount variable (should be in [35,55]) = '35'  
target_date variable (should be in ['2024-04-23','2024-04-26']) = '2024-04-23'  

('The value in EUR of GBP 35.00 on 2024-04-23 = 40.67', 1.1621150493898895)  

cur variable (should == 'GBP') = 'GBP'  
amount variable (should be in [35,55]) = '35'   
target_date variable (should be in['2024-04-23','2024-04-26']) = '2024-04-23' 
  
shape: (2, 3)  

| 'date'       | 'currency' | 'amount' |  
| ------------ | ---------- | -------- | 
| str |str | i64 |  
| '2024-04-23' | 'GBP' | 35 | 
| '2024-04-26' | 'GBP' | 55 |    

What I get:
cur variable (should == 'GBP') = 'currency'  
amount variable (should be in [35,55]) = 'amount'  
target_date variable (should be in ['2024-04-23','2024-04-26']) = 'date'  
<ipython-input-54-af6c7326a981>:7: UserWarning: Overriding existing custom namespace 'myconversions' (on 'LazyFrame')  
class ConversionOperations:  
___________________________________________________  
TypeError      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-af6c7326a981> in <cell line: 17>()   
      15 df = pl.scan_csv('test.csv').collect()  
      16 print(df)  
 ---> 17 df = pl.scan_csv('test.csv').myconversions.convert().collect()  
      18 print(df)  
  
 <ipython-input-54-af6c7326a981> in convert(self)  
      11     def convert(self) -> pl.LazyFrame:  
      12         return self._ldf.with_columns(  
 ---> 13             get_single_rate("currency","amount","date")[0])   
      14  
      15 df = pl.scan_csv('test.csv').collect()   
  
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable    


Can you add the full code of get_single_rate() so we can run your example? The error looks like it's coming from ECB[cur] i.e. from calling get_single_rate("currency", ...) and not from Polars passing column names.

@jqurious thank you for your request. However, there are a number of layers of abstraction behind that function - if you look at the three result rows below the table in the screengrab, they are produced by the first line of def get_single_rate(cur,amount,target_date,reverse = True): which reads print("cur variable (should == 'GBP') = '{}'\namount variable (should be in [35,55]) = '{}'\ntarget_date variable (should be in ['2024-04-23','2024-04-26']) = '{}'\n ".format(cur,amount,target_date)) you could merely use that oneline to replicate. I will also edit the question to show direct input.

Essentially we have: df.with_columns(get_single_rate("currency","amount","date")) but get_single_rate("currency", ...) is executed first so Polars never sees "currency", "amount", "date", ...

There is a page in the docs which I cannot now track down, which I based my attempt on.... I have also tried oneline df = pl.scan_csv('test.csv').with_columns(get_single_rate(pl.col("currency"),pl.col("amount"),pl.col("date"))[0]).collect() which gave
cur variable (should == 'GBP') = 'col("currency")'
amount variable (should be in [35,55]) = 'col("amount")'
target_date variable (should be in ['2024-04-23','2024-04-26']) = 'col("date")'
Any other ideas?

If you want to use currency/date values as keys in ECB, the recommendation would be to turn ECB into a DataFrame and use .join() - Currently you're trying to run a UDF (user-defined-function) on each row which would need .map_elements() but that should only be used when absolutely required. (i.e. when you cannot perform a task in native Polars functionality).

Did you manage to progress on this? The extension stuff sort of hides the issue here. Perhaps if you reduce it down to just df, get_single_rate and ECB in order to get that functionality working first it would help.
